# Eclipselink persist relation table create select

Tags: java, eclipselink, persistence

I'm having this entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "VEHICULE")
public class Vehicule {

    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false, name = "NUMERO")
    private String numero;
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "RAME_VEHICULE")
public class RameVehicule {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "VEHICULE_NUMERO")
    private Vehicule vehicule;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "RAME_ID")
    private Rame rame;

}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "RAME")
public class Rame {

 @Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "RAME_SEQ")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "RAME_SEQ", sequenceName = "RAME_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
@Column(nullable = false, name = "ID")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "NUMERO")
private String numero;
```

and when I m creating a new RameVehicule i m doing this when i want to save the entity after set Rame and Vehicule (rame and vehicule already exist in database):

```
  entityManager.persist(rameVehicule);
```

and in postgresql.log i see :

```
durée : 2.000 ms, lien S_10 : select nextval('RAME_VEHICULE_SEQ')
exécute S_10: select nextval('RAME_VEHICULE_SEQ')
durée : 6.000 ms
exécute S_1: SELECT ID FROM RAME WHERE (ID = $1)
:  paramètres : $1 = '3059211'
durée : 1.000 ms
exécute S_9: SELECT NUMERO FROM VEHICULE WHERE (NUMERO = $1)
:  paramètres : $1 = 'Z27717'
durée : 1.000 ms
exécute S_13: INSERT INTO RAME_VEHICULE (ID, DATE_DEBUT_VALIDITE, DATE_FIN_VALIDITE, RANG, RAME_ID, VEHICULE_NUMERO) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6)
:  paramètres : $1 = '69807', $2 = '2017-02-13 06:03:00', $3 = '2017-02-13 06:08:00', $4 = '0', $5 = '3059211', $6 = 'Z27717'
durée : 1.000 ms
```

why Eclipselink generate select on vehicule and rame before the insert into?

how can avoid this?

thanks!

Comment: How are you getting the Rame and Vehicule instances to set in the RameVehicule instance?

Comment: vehicule is get with : Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT v FROM Vehicule v"); and rame : new object Rame  with rame = entityManager.persist(rame); so i already have the object but in different transaction, but if i already have the object insert juste need the foreign key as id, i don t understand...

Comment: Try testing it such that you actually remove one of the tables before your persist call - intentionally making it throw an exception when it tries to perform the select. This will show exactly where the call is being initiated from and might help find a way to avoid it. It looks like a simple find call to me though, so its hard to say why it is occurring without a complete test case.